# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was doing this exercise and I had to write a program that takes in a list of numbers and swaps pairs of numbers so they're in order:

```
void swapPairs(int* a[], int length)
{
   int i=0;
   int temp;
   while(i<(length-1))
   {
     if(a[i]>a[i+1])
     {
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[i+1];
        a[i+1]=temp;
     }
     i++;
   }
}

int main()
{
  int array[]={2,1,3,1};
  swapPairs(array, 4);
  return 0;
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
In function ‘swapPairs’:
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
     temp=a[i];
         ^

warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
     a[i+1]=temp;


In function ‘main’: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘swapPairs’ from incompatible pointer type
swapPairs(array, 4);
         ^

note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
void swapPairs(int* a[], int length)
  ^
```

When I tried it with just an array instead of a pointer, it worked perfectly fine. Can someone please explain what is wrong with this and how to fix it?

  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int* a[]` change that to `int a[]`

Answer (score 2):

Your declaration of `swapPairs` is wrong - it shouldn't accept an array of `int *` (`int` pointers) - it should accept and an array of `int`s:

```
void swapPairs(int a[], int length)
```

Comment: my question had two parts; first i had to write it with int a[] as the parameter and then say how i would change it if the parameter instead was int* a[]. thats the part i m stuck on

Comment: @ajia that is also coincidentally the part you *left out* of your posted question. We're not mind-readers.

Comment: @ajia `int *a[]` is not "a list of numbers" as you said in your question. It would help if you showed the code which will call the version with `int *a[]`

Comment: I did. I have exactly the same code for both except the other one had just int a[] as a parameter instead.

Comment: nevermind. I think the question was wrong to begin with

Answer (score 1):

The type of 'temp' is int.  The type of 'a[i]' is *int (pointer to an int).

You are assigning the value of a pointer rather than the value of an integer because you are failing to dereference the pointer.

The while loop should read:

```
    while(i<(length-1))
    {
        if(*(a[i])>*(a[i+1]))
        {
             temp=*(a[i]);
             *(a[i])=*(a[i+1]);
             *(a[i+1])=temp;
        }
        i++;
    }
```